# Visible lines beetween textures in SkyBox?

Tags: opengl, textures, lwjgl

I made a skybox in opengl using five textures on five quads, the problem is that the lines(boarders) between the textures are visible:

[image: lazy2]

How do you get of those lines?

```
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
GL11.glVertex3f(-15.0f,-14.0f,-15.0f); 
GL11.glTexCoord2f(1f, 1.0f);
GL11.glVertex3f(15.0f,-14.0f,-15.0f); 
GL11.glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
GL11.glVertex3f(15.0f,16.0f,-15.0f); 
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0f);
GL11.glVertex3f(-15.0f,16.0f,-15.0f); 
GL11.glEnd();
```

This is one quad of the skybox, should it be done differently?

Comment: That is definitely a skybox. You're not unintentionally telling it to draw the vertices as well, are you? This would result in the textures and the black lines you are seeing.

Comment: Are you using `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` for `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T`?

Comment: GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS); 
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);GL11.glVertex3f(-15.0f,-14.0f,-15.0f);   
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1f, 1.0f);GL11.glVertex3f(15.0f,-14.0f,-15.0f);    
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);GL11.glVertex3f(15.0f,16.0f,-15.0f);    
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0f);GL11.glVertex3f(-15.0f,16.0f,-15.0f);     
 GL11.glEnd();  This is one quad of the skybox, should it be done differently?

Comment: @Borut Flis: Maybe you should add the code to your question instead of as a comment. And as genpfault mentioned: What wrapping modes do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem till I set the wrap mode to GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE.
Put this code after you gave the image data to the shader and the seems should be gone:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem in OpenSceneGraph and adapted the OpenGL solution, which should be pretty straight forward. Basically just use `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS)` when your program starts before you start your rendering loop and the lines should disappear.

There was some ambiguity in my research, and it is possible that the enum is actually `GL_TEXTURE_CUBEMAP_SEAMLESS`, but one or the other should work for you. It is a bit more complicated in OSG because you need to `#define GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS 0x884F` then enable seamless cubemapping by using `state->setMode(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS, osg::StateAttribute::ON)`, where state is a state set from the root of your scene graph.

I hope this helps, it worked for me.